# A code issue to be fixed in the Gurobi /python interface

Tags: python, gurobi

I have done a lot of effort and formulated a model to be optimized by Gurobi/python interface in the area of the vehicle routing problem (DARP in particular).
I have a code that shows ''Model is infeasible''
This happens although it is a model that is tested in a published paper.
I have a doubt about my formulation. Anyway, where at StackExchange I can find help with this regard.

Comment: Nowhere on SE without posting reproducible code for your problem...

Comment: I can share the whole code but it should not be publicly @AKX

Comment: Then what you probably need is to hire a consultant.

Comment: where can i do that please? @AKX

Comment: I googled "gurobi consultant" and found https://www.gurobi.com/partners/consulting-services/